# Capture data and then create a loop in existing code

Tags: excel, vba

I've created a spreadsheet that has a macro that will delete and move to a new tab a row when the status in column A is marked 'paid'. I need to take that one step further so that if the status is marked 'paid' and invoice number in column D matches the same row that all same invoice #s will also be moved to the new tab.

What is the code that will capture the invoice number of that row?

Then do another for loop inside the first one that loops through all the rows and moves all those that match the invoice number to insert After `If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = "paid"`. current spreadsheet image. The code that I am using is below. The image is a snippit of the spreadsheet. In the example Sarah Phillips has data in rows 9-12 with 'paid' status in column A row 9. I need all 4 that has the same invoice # to move to the new spreadsheet.

I'm new to writing code and it was suggested that I capture the invoice number of that row then dow a loop inside the first one that loops through all rows and moves those as well. I do not know how to do this or amend the current code so that will include the suggestion.

```
Sub TransferData()

Dim xRg As Range
Dim xCell As Range
Dim I As Long, J As Long, K As Long

I = Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count
J = Worksheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Rows.Count
If J = 1 Then
   If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Sheet2").UsedRange) = 0 Then J = 0
End If
Set xRg = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A" & I)
On Error Resume Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For K = 1 To xRg.Count
    If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = "paid" Then
        xRg(K).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & J + 1)
        xRg(K).EntireRow.Delete
        If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = "paid" Then
            K = K - 1
        End If
        J = J + 1
    End If
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True


 End Sub
```

I expect the rows with matching Invoice numbers to all be moved when row A is marked 'paid' and the macro executed.

[image]

Comment: How many lines of data do you typical have? I ask as its quicker to use arrays etc. but if its just a few lines each time a quick `for each` loop may suffice

Comment: also if you are deleting `row` or `col` ensure you work BACKWARDS!

Comment: The lines of data will be unknown as it will depend on how many times a person is contacted to collect.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the following changes.

- Use a `For` loop. It's easier and you'll be able to follow along easier.
- Delete your rows at the end of your macro. This can be done with the `KillRnG` in the code below.
- You can use the `Offset` to gather information from other columns on the matching row. See my example.

  ```
  'If you insert this immediately after you turn off screen 
  'updating you can loop through your rows.
  dim aCell as Range
  For Each aCell In Intersect(Range("A:A", ActiveCell.UsedRange)).Cells

      If UCase(aCell.Value) = "PAID" Then
          'do your thing of copying the row to some other other sheet.

           'set the row for deletion... this will be done at the end.
            Set killRNG = Union(killRNG, aCell.EntireRow)

      Debug.Print "This is the invoice: " & aCell.Offset(0, 3).Value
  End If

  Next cell

  'This will delete whatever you wanted
  killRNG.ClearContents
  killRNG.Delete
  ```